# .appendTo is not working in phonegap app for blackberry

Tags: jquery, blackberry, cordova

I'm using jqm-calendar in my phonegap app to display calender.

In the calender page below calender there is ul list of jqm in this list li items are not loaded.

issue is for only blackberry device it is working fine on android and iphone builds.

Issue is on line:

```
 e("<li>" + c + "</li>").appendTo(f);
```

i have tried all commented options also but not a single `<li>` item is loaded when debug on device.

```
(function (e) {
e.jqmCalendar = function (t, n) {
    function l() {
        i.settings = e.extend({}, r, n);
        o = e("<table/>");
        var t = e("<thead/>").appendTo(o),
            l = e("<tr/>").appendTo(t),
            c = e("<th class='ui-bar-" + i.settings.theme + " header' colspan='7'/>");
        $previous = e("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-iconpos='notext' class='previous-btn'>Previous</a>").click(function (e) {
            y(new Date(i.settings.date.getFullYear(), i.settings.date.getMonth() - 1, i.settings.date.getDate()))
        }).appendTo(c);
        u = e("<span/>").appendTo(c);
        $previous = e("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-iconpos='notext' class='next-btn'>Next</a>").click(function (e) {
            y(new Date(i.settings.date.getFullYear(), i.settings.date.getMonth() + 1, i.settings.date.getDate()))
        }).appendTo(c);
        c.appendTo(l);
        l = e("<tr/>").appendTo(t);
        for (var h = 0, p = [].concat(i.settings.days, i.settings.days).splice(i.settings.startOfWeek, 7); h < 7; h++) {
            l.append("<th class='ui-bar-" + i.settings.theme + "'><span class='hidden'>" + p[h] + "</span></th>")
        }
        a = e("<tbody/>").appendTo(o);
        o.appendTo(s);
        f = e("<ul data-role='listview' class='bdnamelist'/>").insertAfter(o);
        console.log(f);
        y(i.settings.date)
    }


 s.bind("change", function (t, n) {
        var r = new Date(n.getFullYear(), n.getMonth(), n.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var s = i.settings.events[0];
        //console.log("DEMO begin: " + n + " rows found.");
        //console.log("DEMO end: " + r + " rows found.");
        console.log("DEMO event: " + s + " rows found.");
        f.empty();
        for (var o = 0, t; t = i.settings.events[o]; o++) {
            if (t[i.settings.end] >= n && t[i.settings.begin] <= r) {
                var u = t[i.settings.summary],
                    a = (t[i.settings.begin] > n ? t[i.settings.begin] : n).toTimeString().substr(0, 5),
                    l = (t[i.settings.end] < r ? t[i.settings.end] : r).toTimeString().substr(0, 5),
                    c = t[i.settings.meb_name],
                    h = a + "-" + l;
                //e("<li>" + c + "</li>").appendTo(f);
                //e("<li>" + c + "</li>").appendTo(".bdnamelist");
                  e($('<li></li>').html(c)).appendTo(f);                    
                console.log(f);                 
            }
        }
        f.trigger("create").filter(".ui-listview").listview("refresh")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoa those variable names are rather confusing. Why don't you min later on?
The original line is

```
 $("<li>" + (( timeString != "00:00-00:00") ? timeString : "" ) + " " + summary + "</li>").appendTo($listview);
```

Which indeed can be replaced with:

```
var str = ((timeString != "00:00-00:00") ? timeString : "" ) + " " + summary;
$("<li>").html(str).appendTo($listview);
```

This function requires $ (in your case e) to be jQuery, and $listview to be an jQuery element. This is an really basic jQuery operation, so the program probably doesn't fail at this point. Do the dots show up at the correct dates? Maybe BB parses dates a bit differently. By the way, is there an error thrown and does your log message show up?